# Overflow of bootstrap dropdown in ng-grid

Tags: c#, css, angularjs, overflow, ng-grid

I have ng-grid in my application. In my .ngviewport i have used overflow-x:auto. I want horizontal scrollbar alone and i am able to do it successfully. The problem  now is when i click the name of each row an bootstrap dropdown will appear. For the last row alone this bootstrap is half hided within horizontal scrollbar. When i remove overflow-x from ngview port the bootstrap is coming beyond ng-grid and its fully visible. But by doing this horizontal scrollbar is hidden.I want horizontal scrollbar but at the same time i want bootstrap dropdown of last row to visible fully. Is there any work around for this in css.

Comment: try changing the position of the drop down and fix its z index appropriately.some plunker can help further